# Xiaomi Redmi 7A switchses off by itself

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui

Maybe someone can helps me in this situation. I have Xiaomi Redmi 7A phone and it switches off by itself quiet often. After switched off I spend about 5-10 minutes to run up it by pressing on buutoms end trying fast reboot or hard reboot. Almost all times I get the fast reboot, but pressing the butomms takes 5-10 minutes times. I try to explain that it isn't turn on after power buttom(or even one of volume buttoms have been pressing for 10-20 seconds) for first, second or third time. And I have to try and try to turn on this phone. Is this problem linked with operating system. Independ a power charher is on or off, battery low or high level, it switched off by itself in almost all situations.
Is problem in the operating systems? If you think in this way, please write some ways to find logs or simply figgure out errors. I leave version off operating system here maybe that will be useful in my case. Thank you for your attention and help!
Version MIUI global 12.0.2 Stable
Version Android 10QKQ1.191014.001
Model M1903C3EG
communication model firmware 9_GENNS_PACK-2.372929.3.379151.2

any useful information, advice, solution regarding my problem